# Scroll to a Range on a Microsoft Word Split Window

Tags: c#, .net, office-addins

I'm using the following code on a ribbon button click to spit the MS word Window,

```
private void RibbonButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) {

 Window win = (Window) e.Control.Context;
 win.SplitVertical = 50;

}
```

I need to scroll to specific Ranges on each of the Split views. I tried selecting Ranges using the following code,

```
Panes panes = win.Panes;
foreach(Pane pane in panes){                                    
   Range r = pane.Document.Range(400, 405); // Sample range for testing                         
   r.Select();
}
```

But this code only scrolls to the Range on the Bottom view, but it does not scroll the top view.

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to activate the pane as follows,

```
Panes panes = win.Panes;
   foreach(Pane pane in panes){
       pane.Activate(); // Activate the Pane                                  
       Range r = pane.Document.Range(400, 405); // Sample range for testing                         
       r.Select();
    }
```